# Do we need to add any code in build.gradle for obfuscation if we enabled R8 in gradle.properties?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio 3.1.2 we have a new feature for shrinking and obfuscating code by adding following code in **gradle.properties** file

```
android.enableR8 = true
```

If we do this then do we need to write the old code in **build.gradle** for code shrink and code obfuscation ?

that is,

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

Can we avoid the above 2 lines of code or we still have to keep this ?

source : https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android Preview 3.3 Cannery, **yes** you have to specify those lines.

Example of debug with minified enabled:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```